# Cannot launch new MapActivity

Tags: android, mapactivity

I've been trying to create what I would have imagined would be a rather simple application - on the start activity, there is a button to press and that will then launch a MapActivity displaying your current location.

However, whenever I press the button, I immediately a receive an error and am forced to quit the application.

Here's the log:

```
10-23 19:15:10.826: D/PhoneWindow(3227): DebugMonitor class=com.android.find.my.friends.MainActivity focus=true
10-23 19:15:19.496: D/AndroidRuntime(3227): Shutting down VM
10-23 19:15:19.496: W/dalvikvm(3227): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001db88)
10-23 19:15:19.496: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.find.my.friends/com.android.find.my.friends.ShowMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1843)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4321)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at com.android.find.my.friends.ShowMap.onCreate(ShowMap.java:30)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
10-23 19:15:19.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     ... 11 more
10-23 19:15:19.516: I/dalvikvm(3227): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
10-23 19:15:19.546: I/dalvikvm(3227): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I am testing this on an HTC Tattoo running Android 1.6. I have also previously been able to create an app which displays just the MapActivity.

Any help guys?

[Edit]

Here's my onCreate method:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoom 1 is world view
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

}
```

Comment: Put a break-point into ShowMap.onCreate at line 30, you have nullpointerexception there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a `NullPointerException` at line 30 in your `ShowMap` class. If you could post your `onCreate` method and line 30 I can help you figure out why.

Could you also paste the line that the exception happens on by itself? It is possible that `findViewById` returns null, in which case your `mapView` will be null. Make sure the layout that your MapView is defined in is the same layout that you pass into `setContentView`.

Comment: I pretty much just copied the code from here, so maybe you would get a better picture if i just sent the link: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#googlemaps

(look at the "Google Maps" section)

Comment: But you have a main activity where you press a button, which takes you to the map activity correct? I think the problem might be that you are calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in your map activity when you want to call `setContentView(R.layout.map)`, or whatever you called your xml file with the map layout.

Comment: thank you! yes that was right, massive noob error, thanks for pointing it out :)